# Why geom_line legend if show.legend = FALSE and why different colours

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, legend

After executing the code here below, I was wondering:

1- Why "A.line" and "B.line" variables appear in the geom_point() legend.

2- why there are four colors in the legend.

I guess both answers are related, but I can not tell what is going on.

I would like to have the legend just with "A.points" and "B.points".

I would also like the same colors in both lines and points (I guess this I can do manually).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Best,
David

```
data.frame(x = rep(1:2,2),
           names.points = rep(c("A.point","B.point"), 2),
           y.point = c(2, 4, 7, 9),
           names.lines = rep(c("A.line","B.line"), each = 2),
           y.line = c(3, 3, 8, 8)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y.point, group = names.points, colour = names.points), size = 5) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y.line, group = names.lines, colour = names.lines), show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legends are not related to `geom`s but to the `scale`s and display the categories (or the range of the values) mapped on an aesthetic. Hence, you get four colors because you have four categories mapped on the color aesthetic. The `geom`s used are only displayed in the legend key via the so called key glyph which is a point for `geom_point` and a line for `geom_line`. And  `show.legend=FALSE` only means to not display the key glyph for `geom_line` in the legend key, i.e. the legend keys shows only a point but no line.

To remove the categories related to the lines from your legend use e.g. the `breaks` argument of `scale_color_discrete` instead.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data.frame(
  x = rep(1:2, 2),
  names.points = rep(c("A.point", "B.point"), 2),
  y.point = c(2, 4, 7, 9),
  names.lines = rep(c("A.line", "B.line"), each = 2),
  y.line = c(3, 3, 8, 8)
) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y.point, group = names.points, colour = names.points), size = 5) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y.line, group = names.lines, colour = names.lines), show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_discrete(breaks = c("A.point", "B.point"))
```

[image]

**UPDATE** To fix your issue with the colors you could use a named color vector:

```
pal_col <- rep(c("darkblue","darkred"), 2)
names(pal_col) <- c("A.point", "B.point", "A.line", "B.line")

data.frame(
  x = rep(1:2, 2),
  names.points = rep(c("A.point", "B.point"), 2),
  y.point = c(2, 4, 7, 9),
  names.lines = rep(c("A.line", "B.line"), each = 2),
  y.line = c(3, 3, 8, 8)
) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y.point, group = names.points, colour = names.points), size = 5) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y.line, group = names.lines, colour = names.lines), show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks = c("A.point", "B.point"), 
                     values = pal_col)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, stefan. Beautifully explained.

Comment: I am half-way there. I tried `scale_color_discrete()` and got rid of unwanted elements in the legend, but lines stay with the same color. On the otherr hand, if I try `scale_color_manual(breaks = c(""A.point", "B.point", "A.line", "B.line"), values = rep(c("darkblue","darkred"),2))`, geom colours are all fine, but unwanted elements re-appear on the legend; Any hints?

Comment: I just added an update to fix your color issue. Hope I got the colors right. :)

Comment: You nailed it, thanks a lot! Best, David.